# Overlay Text Strips above Render

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

In the animation, Stickfigures would be communicating amongst eachother. Since I don't have voice actors, I'd be using text instead; Specifically, effect strips.

When text effect strips are added, the main render is excluded.

Here's an image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBBQK.jpg

The Final render should include the scene, not just the effect strips.

Comment: if my answer doesn't help, pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: You'll need to set the Composite Blend to Alpha Over. This is a default setting in the latest releases of Blender. If you're not running the latest official Blender version, you should update.

Answer (score 2):

In VSE use Shift-A -> text and move the text above your render like this:

[image]

result:

[image]